# Php - TCP get active connections

Tags: php

How can I get a list of all the active connections (ip addresses) or search to see if a certain ip address is connected to my Php TCP Server on a specific port. I'm not sure if this matters at all, But I'm using the socket_create() method for my TCP Server.

Comment: this would be best done at the OS level

Comment: You could use `shell_exec("netstat")` and parse the output. Or use OS-specific APIs like `/proc/tcp`

Comment: ill add `tcpdump` to the list

Comment: @Barmar If I was to use shell_exec("netstat") is there a way that I could get all the ips connected to that port into a variable? Or does it return an array of ips?

Comment: It returns a string with all the output of the command, just like you would see if you ran it from the shell. You have to parse it to get the information you want.

Comment: output looks like: http://tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-iface.netstat.html

Comment: I'll use those methods then. Thank you so much guys!